# Converting curl cmd to jQuery $.ajax()

Tags: jquery, ajax, curl, basic-authentication

I'm trying to make a api call with jquery ajax, I have curl working for the api, but my ajax is throwing HTTP 500

I have a curl command working that looks like this:

```
curl -u "username:password" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -d '{"foo":"bar"}' http://www.example.com/api
```

I tried ajax like this, but it is not working:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.example.com/api",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password")); 
    },
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: {foo:"bar"},
    success: function (data) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function(){
      alert("Cannot get data");
    }
});
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Unless the API supports cross domain request with CORS, you can't! You can however do the ajax call to the serverside, and then let the server do the cURL stuff.

Comment: @adeneo I'm using custom packaging that does not block cross domain request,  assuming this is same origin, how do I get this to work ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

By default $.ajax() will convert `data` to a query string, if not already a string, since `data` here is an object, change the `data` to a string and then set `processData: false`, so that it is not converted to query string.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.example.com/api",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password")); 
    },
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    processData: false,
    data: '{"foo":"bar"}',
    success: function (data) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function(){
      alert("Cannot get data");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this answered my question, here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30992688/creating-task-using-wunderlist-api/31015511#31015511